# Logging Application Block not logging to a file from workstation

Tags: c#, logging

This is my config for Microsoft Enterprise logging. 
This is not logging from client workstations. It logs correctly from the server. 
What kind of folder C:\temp\logs\PFService.log permissions should it have to log from workstations.

```
<configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging"/>
</configSections>
     <loggingConfiguration name="Logging Application Block" tracingEnabled="false" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
        <listeners>
          <clear />
          <add source="Web Server" formatter="Text Formatter" log="" machineName="." listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" name="Event Log Destination"/>
          <add fileName="c:\temp\logs\PFService.log" formatter="Text Formatter" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollSizeKB="96" rollInterval="Day" name="Rolling File Destination"/>
        </listeners>

        <formatters>
          <clear />
          <add template="{timestamp(local:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff)} {category} - {title}: {message}" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" name="Text Formatter"/>
        </formatters>
        <logFilters>
          <clear />
          <add categoryFilterMode="AllowAllExceptDenied" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.CategoryFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" name="Category"/>
          <add enabled="true" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.LogEnabledFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" name="LogEnabled Filter"/>
        </logFilters>
        <categorySources>
          <add switchValue="All" name="Debug">
            <listeners>
              <add name="Rolling File Destination"/>
            </listeners>
          </add>
          <add switchValue="All" name="Exceptions">
            <listeners>
              <add name="Rolling File Destination"/>
            </listeners>
          </add>
          <add switchValue="All" name="General">
            <listeners>
              <add name="Rolling File Destination"/>
            </listeners>
          </add>
        </categorySources>
        <specialSources>
          <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events"/>
          <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
          <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
            <listeners>
              <add name="Event Log Destination"/>
            </listeners>
          </errors>
        </specialSources>
      </loggingConfiguration>


 public static void Log(string _Title, string _Message, string _Category)
        {
            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();

            logEntry.Title = _Title;
            logEntry.Message = _Message;
            logEntry.Categories.Add(_Category);

            Logger.Write(logEntry);
        }
```

Comment: what's the type of your application?

Comment: Thank you for looking at the post. It is a client server application, asp.net with silverlight. Most of the logging happens on page_load. If I access the aspx page from the server, it logs to a file. But if I access the aspx page from the workstation, none of it is logged.I always want it to log to C:\tem\logs\Pfservice.txt.  C: here refers to the server. So always log it to the server when accessed from worstation

Comment: ok, let me try to understand, you have an asp.net web application where on page load, you are logging something. When you open the page on the server where it is hosted, it is logging correctly and when you open the page on any other machine, it is not logging. Is this a fair understanding of your situation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. When I access the page from the server using this url: https:\\centertest.com\page1.aspx?sso="" . This is the same url I use to access it from the workstation. It logs in the first case from the server. From the workstation it does not log.n

Comment: Is your functionality working fine, when you access the page from any other machine? Is it the problem with only logging? Irrespective of where you are opening the page, the server should be processing the request under the user account you configured in IIS.

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out. The client had his servers screwed up. I ran fiddler to see what it is even pointing to without taking it from the client that he set it right. It was calling a totally different server with similar functionality